# chain of responsibility pattern

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

I am trying to implement the chain of responsibility pattern, but it seems i am missing something because in the concrete classes the setnexthandler is not setting the next but is always the same. I guess my mistake is in the concrete classes in the processMalfunction() method in the else statems next.setNextHandler(next); i think it should be next.setNextHandler(Severity.Medium) for the first one. So here is the code if you could take a look. Here is the code.

```
public interface MalfunctionHandler 
{
    public void processMalfunction(Malfunction malfunciton);
    public void setNextHandler(MalfunctionHandler handler);
}

public enum Severity 
{
    TRIVIAL, LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH
}

public class Malfunction
{
    /**
     * severity is a type of Severity 
     */
    Severity severity;

    /**
     * @param description describes the severity of the problem
     */
    String description;

    Malfunction(Severity severity, String description)
    {
        if(description == null)
        {
            description = "No description available. Probably serious.";
        }

        if(description.isEmpty())
        {
            description = "No description available. Probably serious.";
        }

        this.severity = severity;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Severity getSeverity() 
    {
        return severity;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setSeverity(Severity severity)
    {
        this.severity = severity;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }
}

public class SpaceMonkey implements MalfunctionHandler 
{

    Severity severity;
    MalfunctionHandler next;
    File read = new File("expected-bronze.txt");
    File f = new File("log-bronze.txt");

    SpaceMonkey(Severity severity)
    {
        this.severity = severity;
        System.out.println(FileUtility.readFile(read));
    }

    @Override
    public void processMalfunction(Malfunction malfunction)
    {
        if (malfunction.getSeverity() == Severity.LOW)
        {
           final String[] splits = FileUtility.readFile(read).split("problem.");
            for (String asset : splits)
            {
                if (asset.contains("Space monkey"))
                {
                     FileUtility.writeFile(f, asset + "problem."); 
                     System.out.println(asset + "problem.");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            next.setNextHandler(next);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setNextHandler(MalfunctionHandler next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public class ServiceRobot implements MalfunctionHandler
{

    Severity severity;
    MalfunctionHandler next;
     File read = new File("expected-bronze.txt");
      File f = new File("log-bronze.txt");

    ServiceRobot(Severity severity)
    {
        this.severity = severity;
    }


    @Override
    public void processMalfunction(Malfunction malfuntion) 
    {


        if (this.severity == severity)
        {
            String[] splits = FileUtility.readFile(read).split("problem.");
         for(String asset : splits)
        {
            if(asset.contains("Service robot"))
            {                  
                 FileUtility.writeFile(f, asset + "problem."); 
                 System.out.println(asset + "problem.");

            }
        }
        }
        else
        {
            next.setNextHandler(next);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setNextHandler(MalfunctionHandler next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

}

public class Engineer implements MalfunctionHandler
{

    Severity severity;
    MalfunctionHandler next;
    File read = new File("expected-bronze.txt");

    Engineer(Severity severity)
    {
        this.severity = severity;
    }


    @Override
    public void processMalfunction(Malfunction malfuntion)
    {
        File f = new File("log-bronze.txt");

        if (this.severity == severity)
        {
            String[] splits = FileUtility.readFile(read).split("problem.");
         for(String asset : splits)
        {
            if(asset.contains("Engineer"))
            {
                 FileUtility.writeFile(f, asset + "problem."); 
                 System.out.println(asset + "problem.");

            }
        }
        }
        else
        {
            next.setNextHandler(next);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setNextHandler(MalfunctionHandler next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

}

public class Captain implements MalfunctionHandler
{
    Severity severity;
    MalfunctionHandler next;
    File read = new File("expected-bronze.txt");

    Captain(Severity severity)
    {
        this.severity = severity;
    }
    @Override
    public void processMalfunction(Malfunction malfuntion)
    {
        File f = new File("log-bronze.txt");

        if (this.severity == severity)
        {
            String[] splits = FileUtility.readFile(read).split("problem.");
         for(String asset : splits)
        {
            if(asset.contains("Captain"))
            {
                 FileUtility.writeFile(f, asset + "problem."); 
                 System.out.println(asset + "problem.");

            }
        }
        }
        else
        {
            next.setNextHandler(next);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setNextHandler(MalfunctionHandler next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

}

public class FileUtility 
{

    /** This method appends a single string to a text file.
     * 
     * @param f The file to write to
     * @param entry The string to append
     */
    public static void writeFile(File f, String entry) 
    {
        try 
        {
            final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
            out.write(entry);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Problem writing to the file");
        }
    }

    /** This method resets the named text file.
     * 
     * @param f The file to reset
     */
    public static void resetFile(File f) {
        try {
            final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, false));
            out.write("");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem reset the file");
        }
    }

    /** This method reads the contents of a text file.
     * 
     * @param f The file to read from
     * @return the contents of the text file as a single string
     */
    public static String readFile(File f) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem reading from file");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}


public class MalfunctionHandlerTest {

    /**
     * No-args constructor.
     */
    public MalfunctionHandlerTest() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of processMalfunction method.
     */
    @Test
    public void testProcessMalfunction() {

        // Instanciate malfunction handlers
        final SpaceMonkey sm = new SpaceMonkey(Severity.TRIVIAL);
        final ServiceRobot sr = new ServiceRobot(Severity.LOW);
        final Engineer e = new Engineer(Severity.MEDIUM);
        final Captain c = new Captain(Severity.HIGH);

        // Construct chain of responsbility
        sm.setNextHandler(sr); 
        sr.setNextHandler(e);
        e.setNextHandler(c);

        // Create malfunctions
        final Malfunction m1 = new Malfunction(Severity.HIGH, "Life support error. Oxygen "
                 + "Recycling unit damaged, running at half efficiency");      
        final Malfunction m2  = new Malfunction(Severity.LOW, "Communications error. Cannot "
                + "find Jazz FM");
        final Malfunction m3 = new Malfunction(Severity.MEDIUM, "Power supply error. Solar Panel "
                + "2 damaged, running at 31.3333% efficiency");
        final Malfunction m4 = new Malfunction(Severity.MEDIUM, "Thermal regulation error. Sensor "
                + "damaged, manual temperature regulation needed");
        final Malfunction m5 = new Malfunction(Severity.TRIVIAL, "Trash can full on C-Desk.");
        final Malfunction m6 = new Malfunction(Severity.LOW, "Shower plug hole full of monkey hair");
        final Malfunction m7 = new Malfunction(Severity.HIGH, "Proximity alert. Collision imminent");

        // Clean log file
        FileUtility.resetFile(new File("log-bronze.txt"));

        // Process malfunctions
        sm.processMalfunction(m1);
        sm.processMalfunction(m2);
        sm.processMalfunction(m3);
        sm.processMalfunction(m4);
        sm.processMalfunction(m5);
        sm.processMalfunction(m6);
        sm.processMalfunction(m7);

        // Check log file
        final String actualOutput = FileUtility.readFile(new File("log-bronze.txt"));
        final String expectedOutput = FileUtility.readFile(new File("expected-bronze.txt"));
        assertEquals(actualOutput, expectedOutput);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any chain setup here. The principle of the pattern is to have each link of the chain do its part, and then call the next link somehow.

So a method should look like the following:

```
public void processMalfunction(Malfunction malfunction) {
    doSomething();
    this.next.processMalfunction(malfunction);
}
```

And of course, the chain should be setup before, using something like

```
Link1 start = new Link1();
Link2 link2 = new Link2();
start.setNextHandler(link2);
Link3 link3 = new Link3();
link2.setNextHandler(link3);
...
```

Your current code consists in doing something if some condition is true, else assign the next handler of the next handler to itself:

```
next.setNextHandler(next);
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not provide the test class I was assuming it was not neccessary. I edited it now.

Comment: My point still stands, though: no link ever calls the next link in your chain. And a link shouldn't modify the structure of the chain: that's not its responsibility.

Comment: In your comment you have mentioned that A Chain do its part and then forward to others, but better implementation is that if Chain is not able to perform that task then only it forwards. If chain can handle the request it returns back it client.